# Reading local file to open in Android WebView using URL

Tags: android, html, kotlin, android-webview

I want to read a local html file to open it in Android WebView.

Why does the following work:

```
webViewMain.apply {
            loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
        }
```

But this code

```
webViewMain.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
            URL("file:///android_asset/index.html").readText(Charset.forName("UTF-8")),
            "text/html",
            "UTF-8",
            null)
```

gives me the following error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/index.html`

Comment: Files in assets are not considered local. Please tell where you have your files.

Comment: The files I want to load are in `app/src/main/assets/...` folder of my project.

Comment: `URL("file:///android_asset/index.html").readText()` That will not work and gives you your exception. The question is not why this does not work but why you think thtat such a construct could work. The question is also why you are not content with your first solulution.

Comment: If you wanna read the text of a file in assets resource you should use something like getAssets().openInputStream("index.html");  and read the text from the stream. But then still is unclear why you would read the text in this way. Just use your first solution and .js an .css files will be read by the WebView too.

Comment: `app/src/main/assets/... folder of my project. `  Indeed. That is a folder on your development machine. Not on your Android device. On your Android device assets becomes a resource.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70933079/android-studio-inputstream-form-url-problem

Answer (score 1):

The android file should be in the assets folder which is part of the root directory of the project.

`assets/index.html`

If you see the structure in the explorer it will be

`/app/src/main/assets/index.html`

and call `webViewMain.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");`

Things to check:

Make sure your assets folder spelling is right

The file is in the correct directory since it's giving you a `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: I used IDE to create the asset folder so spelling should be fine. And I am able to load the file with `webView.apply { loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html") }` into my WebView. However, since I want to include JS files I was recommended to use `loadDataWithBaseURL(...)` instead. But using the second command with the arguments above does not work.