# android studio inputStream form URL problem

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, inputstream

I'm using this code for bypass the css from WebView loading , I used asset folder for loading my own css but now I need to load my custom css from URL because I need to Change my Css every week .
probelm is : after change InputStream to URL my css bypass is note working !!
My old code is :

```
 private void injectCSS() {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("style.css");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        inputStream.close();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                "var style = document.createElement('style');" +
                "style.type = 'text/css';" +
                // Tell the browser to BASE64-decode the string into your script !!!
                "style.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                "parent.appendChild(style)" +
                "})()");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and My New code is : > but is not working

```
  private void injectCSS() {
    try {
        final InputStream inputStream = new URL("https://sitemname.ir/app/style.css").openStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        inputStream.close();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                "var style = document.createElement('style');" +
                "style.type = 'text/css';" +
                // Tell the browser to BASE64-decode the string into your script !!!
                "style.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                "parent.appendChild(style)" +
                "})()");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does not work exactly? Should we guess?

Comment: InputStream is not working after get file from URL

Comment: Again: what exactly happens? Or what happens instead? Or what does not happen? Should we guess? Any exception? Why dont you have a Toast() in that catch block?

Comment: my code was Inject CSS by style.css from assets folder but now i need css from site (url) not from folder - i used inputStream url but it's not working